# Understanding the presentation of viewControllers

Tags: xcode4.5

I have a conceptual question regarding viewControllers and the "presentation".

I am trying to figure out the "good" way to show my content.

Lets say I have 2 views (viewControllers).

I now want to navigate from view1 to view2. Using either a button or some other event.

I notice there is the "presentViewController" - and that this involves "dismiss". I suppose that means that view2 is sort of stacked on top of view1?

What if view1 is only used for a startup login - so that you dont ever get back to this view, unless you quit or logout? Would you still "present" and "dismiss"? (so that view1 is always present, but hidden beneath view2 - and maybe even view3, view4 and so on)

My guess is that I should go to view2 and completely replace view1? How? 
How many ways can you present a viewController? And when do you use each?

Does my question make any sense?

Thx
John

Comment: You used **irrelevant tags only...**

Comment: So I did?! How on earth did that happen?! I was convinced I chose the exact same tags I just edited to now. I wrote xcode in the field and could chose a from a list of xcode tags. I chose 2. And somehow they turned into cocoa touch stuff.... Anyway. I proabably missed something. Sorry.